# Is there a way to run a shiny app in a local server so everyone in the company can have access?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

i'm actually doing an internship and i'm building a tool with r shiny. But in the company, they exclusively work with windows, so i wanted to know if there is a way to run a shinny app in a local server without LINUX ?

Comment: Shiny server version is available only for LINUX machines.
You can share your app in localhost, but not in server side other than linux.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858196/r-shiny-webserver-on-a-local-server

Comment: Oh nice thank you, it seems that there is a way to share it. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to share Shiny apps on Windows. I built a package called RInno that helps deploy them on desktop computers. You can create a gist on github and other users can run the app from there, or you can create a Linux environment on a windows server with a VM

Answer (score 5):

You don't need shiny server.  Add a line to your shiny script:

```
options(shiny.host={your local ip address})
```

Find your local ip address using ifconfig on Linux or ipconfig on Windows.  Shiny will start serving on the local ip.  Then just tell people your ip and port.  Also you will have to open that port on your firewall.  As an example, you can access my Shiny site at http://162.226.218.159:7750.

Comment: Just note that workplace firewalls can be the reason this might not appear to work.